# Strange results of `Date?.toString(format:)`

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a very strange behaviour in my app. This code:

```
var timestamp: Date?
...
timestamp?.toString(format: "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

produces some unexpected results. In 99.99% of cases everything works fine and the correct string is sent to my server. However, there was an extremely rare situation when the result which came to my server was

```
2018020671122 dop.
```

`dop.` is probably a Czech equivalent of `AM`.

I don't understand why this happens. There is no `tt` in my format and it is explicitly stated that I want two digits for hours, not just one. My code works fine on many devices, but it keeps producing the result above on a single device (iPhone 5s, iOS 10). I cannot reach this particular device (it belongs to one of my customer out there). Any idea?

Comment: check for timezone

Comment: That device is probably set to 12h time formatting. You are not setting locale to POSIX, therefore the format is overwritten from `HH` to `hh`. See the linked QA, especially the technical note https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html